# How to ignore a line in TypeScript but copy it to JS?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write TypeScript code that uses an existing JS library. The problem is that this library provides a facility, `include()`, for loading JS classes at run time based on "path" passed to `include()`:

> var LibraryClass = include('path-to-class');

But TypeScript needs definitions of these classes at compile time... I can make my code compile by commenting the whole `include` line (together with `var LibraryClass`) in .ts and providing class definitions the usual TypeScript way, via  `/// <reference path="someFile.ts"/>` or by creating .d.ts ambient definition files for this library.

But I can't figure out how to ignore `include()` calls in .ts but keep them in the resulting .js...

May be it's possible to have different variable names in .ts and .js? If I could, for example, have

> var LibraryClassTS = include('path-to-class');

in TypeScript but, somehow, compile it into

> var LibraryClass = include('path-to-class');

if JavaScript, that would solve my problem: I would have an empty `LibraryClassTS` class in .ts (while `LibraryClass` interface definition is loaded from .d.ts) and the run-time `LibraryClass` loading in .js.

Answer (score 4):

If this is the only place you're using `include` then place this at the top of that file:

```
declare var include: any;
```

If you're using it more throughout your application consider moving it to a `.d.ts` file

But if you're using it in multiple projects maybe you should consider creating a more complete specification for it and submitting that to the definitely typed repo.

Comment: The problem is not with `include`, which I already defined in a .d.ts, but with the class it creates, `LibraryClass`. I have a definition of `LibraryClass` coming from another .d.ts, but `var LibraryClass = ...` creates a different, local, definition...

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to suppress the `include()` line in .ts but allow it in .js:

1) In TypeScript code, commented each `include()` line with `////`, so that TypeScript treats it as a comment (and copied this "comment" to the .js).

2) Made a post-processor script that looks in .js files (which have .ts counterparts) for lines matching `/^(\s*\/{4}).+=\s*\binclude\b\s*\(.*\)/` regular expression and deletes the `////`.

3) Hooked this script to File Watchers plugin in IntelliJ/WebStorm, so that it automatically gets invoked after each TypeScript build.

Answer (score -1):

This can help please check out: /// TS_IGNORE
let a:string = 1:)

Comment: Hello, please add some explanation to your answer, as one-line answers are not suited best on SO.